# How to use swf as thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, flash, actionscript

Here i use an image as thumbnail. when image change to swf file is not working with same code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="../resources/css/fancybox-buttons.css"
    th:href="@{/resources/css/fancybox-buttons.css}" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/resources/js/fancybox-buttons.js}"></script>
```

**jquery function**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',
helpers : {
title : {
type: 'outside'
},
thumbs : {
width : 50,
height : 50
}
}
});
});
```

**Html code**

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_b.jpg" title="Ayvalık, Turkey (Nejdet Düzen)">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

how to do the swf file as thumnail ? and also

when click the thumbnail the swf will play?

please share your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is one of the numerous lightbox possible, We just need to read about how they do this. Looking at their page ( http://fancybox.net/ ) we can see that they link the swf directly in the href attribute of the fancybox. So try this. If this doesn't work, use the "alternate sub-page method" as if you were linking a web page in the box. Doing so, you'll be able to control the object and embed tags usually required for the swf objects.